# uGet takes over internet

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xfce

I have linux mint 19.1 xfce. When i start downloading file with [uGet](https://ugetdm.com/) I cannot browse internet.

Computer runs okay but anything to do with internet is taken over by uGet. When uGet completes the download, i can connect to internet and browse the sites. It is very annoying. any solution?

Many thanks,

Comment: something like ... not using uGet?

Comment: I agree with @mosvy. I would never use a program that used 100% of my bandwidth, just like I'd never use a program that took 100% of my CPU power.

Comment: @mosvy Ha Ha I thought of the same solution but was wondering if any one facing the same problem. Anyways many thanks for reading, Cheers

Comment: I have used uGet for a long time and never faced this. Something else was happening there that will remain unsolved :)